# '() => Promise<T>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T>'

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have an interface:

```
export interface ITreeViewItem {
    getChildren: Promise<ITreeViewItem[]>;
    ...
```

and an implementation of it:

```
export class MyClass implements ITreeViewItem {

  public async getChildren(): Promise<ITreeViewItem[]> {
    let result = await this._fileSystemService.getContents(this.fullPath);
    let items = result.map(x => {
      let y: ITreeViewItem = null;
      return y;
    });
    return items;
  }
  ...
```

For me it looks fine but I get an error:

> Types of property 'getChildren' are incompatible.
>
> Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
>
> Property 'then' is missing in type '() => Promise'.

What is wrong with my `getChildren` implementation?

I am using *TypeScript 2.5.3*.

Comment: In the first code block, you have `getChildren` as a property; In the second code snippet, you have `getChildren` as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `getChildren` on `ITreeViewItem` is not a function returning a promise, it's just a promise. You can declare it as a method, returning a Promise by adding `()`

```
export interface ITreeViewItem {
    getChildren() : Promise<ITreeViewItem[]>;
}
```